# How to add array to includes() javascript

Tags: javascript

Im using composedPath for detect click outer of elements, but if elements more then 1 i need to add them all in if(). Maybe in js have another way? Im trying .includes(document.querySelectorAll(".js-open-user")); But thats not work.

```
document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
let b1 = event
        .composedPath()
        .includes(document.querySelectorAll(".js-open-user")[0]);

let b2 = event
        .composedPath()
        .includes(document.querySelectorAll(".js-open-user")[1]);

let b3 = event
        .composedPath()
        .includes(document.querySelectorAll(".js-open-user")[2]);

if (!b1 && !b2 && !b3) this.closeUser();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a NodeList to an array by using `Array.prototype.slice.call()`.
Then using `Array.prototype.some()` to check that at least one matches the criterion, if not you can use `this.closeUser()` which is not implemented in my example.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
  const openUsers = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.js-open-user'));
  const composedPath = evt.composedPath();
  
  if (!openUsers.some(user => composedPath.includes(user))) {
    // no open users found...
    alert('no matches!');
    return;
  }
  
  alert('match!');
});
```

```html
<div class="js-open-user">hi</div>
<div class="js-open-user">oop</div>
<div class="js-open-user">test</div>
<div class="js-open-user">last one</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".js-open-user");
const intersection = event.composedPath().filter(n => nodes.includes(n));
```

Comment: and how it used in if? like this if(intersection) this.closeNav?